# Error go: module github.com/golang/protobuf is deprecated: Use the "google.golang.org/protobuf" module instead

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto

I am facing an error after generating the code in golang from .proto file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJJvo.png)

I tried this line after searching in stackoverflow :

```
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

and I get :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VprSX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it,
it was a setup issue in the ~/.bashrc file I didn't specify exactly the GOROOT & GOPATH
here's the steps to follow

on your command line

```
nano ~/bashrc
```

then add this lines to the file

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin

export GOPATH=/home/user/golib
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export GOPATH=$GOPATH:/home/user/code
```

save it by clicking `ctrl^X`

all the dependencies will be added ;as I did understand ; to the golib folder

then logout your session

by the way I followed the instructions from freecodecamp video on YouTube

Answer (score -1):

I think you should run

```
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd
```

and generate your code using it.

P.S. after installation the binary will be put to $GOPATH/bin